# why do we use const in for...of loops in javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-of-loop

I am wondering why we use `const` in javascript `for...of` loops. Every example I see using `for...of` loops use `const` while declaring the variable. For example:

```
for (const item of array) {
    // do something
}
```

Is there any reason we don't use `var` like this?

```
for (var item of array) {
    // do something
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var` will load the variable into the global scope, whereas `let` and `const` will declare it in the lexical scope:

```js
const test = [1, 2, 3];

// lexical
for (let testItem of test) {
    console.log(window.testItem);
}

// global
for (var testItem of test) {
    console.log(window.testItem);
}
```

Comment: Bu lexical scope do you mean the scope contained within the curly brackets?

Comment: @I_keep_getting_downvoted Exactly. `let` and `const` basically declare a "temporary" variable that is invisible to anything outside of that `for ... of` loop, but `var` will declare it as a regular global variable, which you can access at `window.testItem`.

Comment: Thanks. The question has been closed before I got to accept your answer. I don't know if I will be able to do so.

Comment: @I_keep_getting_downvoted No worries. I appreciate it.